# Azure Function Still Connected to EventHub After Being Stopped

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure function that reads from an EventHub which is working well. However, when I stop the function app, it is still connected and processing events which I can confirm in the logs.

Is there something else I need to be doing to abort the eventhub connections if I stop the function app?

Comment: Which metric or logs are you referring to?

Comment: In my case, this function is producing messages off the event hub to a SignalR service. I can confirm that the SignalR client is receiving two messages, even though the logs of my active app stated that it produced one. And this did not happen until I started using slots.

Comment: `when I stop the function app` how do you stop the app, are you sure all instances in all slots are stopped?